# Equivalent function to "find in all diagrams" in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am searching for a API function corresponding to the "find in all diagrams"-function (Strg + U) in Enterprise Architect.

The class [element](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/element2.html) provides the attribute diagrams which should return a collection of diagrams but it returns in my case always an empty list. Is it the wrong way?

EDIT:
I would be happy about a function that returns a collection of diagrams which include the element.

THE SOLUTION:

```
public List<EA.Diagram> getAllDiagramsOfElement(EA.Element element){
        String xmlQueryResult = repository.SQLQuery(
                            "select dobj1.Diagram_ID " + 
                            "from t_diagramobjects dobj1 " +
                            "where dobj1.Object_ID = " + element.ElementID+";");
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(xmlQueryResult);
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/EADATA/Dataset_0/Data/Row");
        List<EA.Diagram> result = new List<EA.Diagram>();

        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList){
            result.Add(repository.GetDiagramByID(Convert.ToInt32(xn["Diagram_ID"].InnerText)));
        }
        return result;
}
```

With kind regards
MK

Answer (score 2):

You might have to use a query,

Try this

`select * from t_diagramobjects dobj1, t_diagramobjects dobj2 where dobj1.object_id=dobj2.object_id and dobj1.diagram_id!=dobj2.diagram_id;`

Comment: Thx! This helped me to develop the method.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to stay with the API, you have to walk the packages in the model tree recursively, adding diagrams to a collection (ok, Dictionary object in VBScript). 
Then you find all Diagramobjects from Diagrams. DiagramObjects then relate to Elements (remember, Element may be represented in more Diagrams).

Another approach could be to use Repository.SQLQuery method, which should return XML-formatted resultset (I didn't test that yet). But you'd need MSXML present on the machine to parse it (and keep up with the versions).

Generally, if you want to scan whole model and you don't need parent-child relationships, SQL should be better fit. And vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same function in my [Enterprise Architect Add-in Framework](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework), implemented in the class [ElementWrapper](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/ElementWrapper.cs):

```
//returns a list of diagrams that somehow use this element.
public override HashSet<T> getUsingDiagrams<T>() 
{
    string sqlGetDiagrams = @"select distinct d.Diagram_ID from t_DiagramObjects d
                              where d.Object_ID = " + this.wrappedElement.ElementID;
    List<UML.Diagrams.Diagram> allDiagrams = this.model.getDiagramsByQuery(sqlGetDiagrams).Cast<UML.Diagrams.Diagram>().ToList(); ; ;
    HashSet<T> returnedDiagrams = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (UML.Diagrams.Diagram diagram in allDiagrams)
    {
        if (diagram is T)
        {
            T typedDiagram = (T)diagram;
            if (!returnedDiagrams.Contains(typedDiagram))
            {
                returnedDiagrams.Add(typedDiagram);
            }
        }
    }
    return returnedDiagrams;
}
```

The function `getDiagramsByQuery` in the [Model](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/Model.cs) class looks like this

```
//returns a list of diagrams according to the given query.
//the given query should return a list of diagram id's
public List<Diagram> getDiagramsByQuery(string sqlGetDiagrams)
{
    // get the nodes with the name "Diagram_ID"
    XmlDocument xmlDiagramIDs = this.SQLQuery(sqlGetDiagrams);
    XmlNodeList diagramIDNodes =
        xmlDiagramIDs.SelectNodes(formatXPath("//Diagram_ID"));
    List<Diagram> diagrams = new List<Diagram>();
    foreach (XmlNode diagramIDNode in diagramIDNodes)
    {
        int diagramID;
        if (int.TryParse(diagramIDNode.InnerText, out diagramID))
        {
            Diagram diagram = this.getDiagramByID(diagramID);
            diagrams.Add(diagram);
        }
    }
    return diagrams;
}
```